# Column Name as Variable in PostgreSql Query

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

i was trying to update a table row by row in postgresql using python.

the code used was

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE im_entry.pr_table 
                   SET selected_entry = im_entry.usr_table.",entryn," 
                  FROM im_entry.usr_table 
                 WHERE im_entry.pr_table.image_1d = ",idn,"")
```

...where `entryn` and `idn` are two string variables ( entry1,entry2.. id1,id2..etc)

I am getting an error

> TypeError: function takes at most 3 arguments (5 given)

My table is

```
image_1d | entry1 | entry2 | entry3 | entry4 | entry5 
----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
cursor.execute(
    '''UPDATE im_entry.pr_table 
       SET selected_entry  = im_entry.usr_table.{0}
       FROM im_entry.usr_table 
       WHERE im_entry.pr_table.image_1d = ?'''.format(entryn),[idn])
```

Normally, you would want to call `cursor.execute(sql,args)`, where `sql` is a parametrized sql query, and `args` is a list or tuple of values to be substituted for the parameter placeholders.

For Postgresql, the usual db driver, pyscopg, uses question marks for the parameter placeholders.

Thus, usually, you'd want to use something like

```
sql='''UPDATE im_entry.pr_table 
           SET selected_entry  = ?
           FROM im_entry.usr_table 
           WHERE im_entry.pr_table.image_1d = ?'''
```

but in your case, you aren't trying to set `selected_entry` to a specific value, but rather to a column name. Is that correct? In that case, you unfortunately can't use a parameter placeholder. Instead, you have to use string formatting, which is what I suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind table or column names, only the values associated with them.

Comment: if my values are id1,1d2 etc  can i use  it as idn with idn="id"
idn=idn+str(i)   in query